# Can I check collide_widget using a list?

Tags: kivy

I am trying to make a game where you can move a character around screen and I had it so that if my character ran into a picture of a tree, the character would stop moving.  After getting this to work, What I tried to do was change the code so instead of just using the tree widget, I wanted to iterate through a list of widgets, so that if my character runs into any of these, character stops moving.  What's strange is that it works when I have only one widget in the list.  I can also put list[0] or list[1] in my code and when my character will stop when encountering those widgets.  But again, if I have more than one widget in the list and try to iterate through the list, it does not work, my character does not stop when encountering any of the widgets.

I'm wondering what I did wrong or how to fix this.  Ultimately I want it so that if my character runs into any of the images in the list, the character will stop moving.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import FallOutTransition
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics import Color



gamelayout = FloatLayout(size=(300, 300))
bglayout = FloatLayout()
characterselectionlayout = GridLayout(cols=2)


class Game(Screen):

class Bg(Image):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Bg, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.allow_stretch = True
        self.size_hint = (None, None)
        self.size = (1440, 1440)



class Npcs(Image):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Npcs, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.allow_stretch=True   



class MoveableImage(Image):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MoveableImage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(None, self)
        if not self._keyboard:
            return
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self.on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_up=self.on_keyboard_up)

        self.y = (Window.height/2.1)
        self.app = App.get_running_app()



    def on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode[1] == 'left':
            self.source = 'selectionscreen/left.zip'
            self.anim_delay=.20
            if self.x < (Window.width * .25):
                bglayout.x += 4
            else:
                for i in listofwidgets:
                    if self.collide_widget(i):
                        self.x -=0
                    else:
                        self.x -=6

        elif keycode[1] == 'right':
            self.source ='selectionscreen/right.zip'
            self.anim_delay=.20
            if self.x > (Window.width * .70):
                bglayout.x -= 4
            else:
                for i in listofwidgets:
                    if self.collide_widget(i):
                        self.x += 0
                    else:
                        self.x += 6

        else:
            return False
        return True


class gameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        global sm 
        sm = ScreenManager()
        game = Game(name='game')
        sm.add_widget(game)
        global listofobject
        listofobject = []
        hero = MoveableImage(source='selectionscreen/right1.png', size_hint=(None,None), allow_stretch = False, size=(40, 65))
        self.tree = Npcs(source='selectionscreen/tree.zip', allow_stretch=False, size_hint=(None,None), pos_hint={'x':.20, 'y':.30}, size=(50, 50), pos=(300, 300))
        self.testdude = Npcs(source='selectionscreen/testdude.png', allow_stretch=False, size_hint=(None,None), pos_hint={'x':.60, 'y':.70}, size=(100, 124), pos=(800, 900))
        listofwidgets.append(self.tree)
        listofwidgets.append(self.testdude)
        self.background=Bg(source='selectionscreen/background12.png', pos_hint={'x':0, 'y':0})
        bglayout.add_widget(self.background)
        bglayout.add_widget(self.tree)
        bglayout.add_widget(self.testdude)
        gamelayout.add_widget(bglayout)
        gamelayout.add_widget(hero)
        game.add_widget(gamelayout)

        return sm





if __name__ == '__main__':
    gameApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your overall question...yes, there's no reason you shouldn't be able to.

Tracking down your problem will need more code though...at the moment your snippet doesn't make sense, because `list` isn't defined anywhere. Could you maybe post a short example that runs, or at least the full code you're using?

As a side note, `list` is not a good variable name because it overrides the `list` class instantiator which can be annoying or actively buggy later.

Comment: I updated my code and also changed the list name.  list is defined in the build.